# How to import FastAPI app folder to satisfy pycharm and pylint?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import, fastapi, pylint

I am trying to figure out the best way to manage relative vs absolute imports in my project so that the testing and linting tools from pylint, pytest, vscode and pycharm are all happy and so that the app will run correctly in production.

I have not packaged the app with `setup.py` because it is installed into a docker image and run from its working directory. My project directory structure is like this:

```
app
 ┣ app
 ┃ ┣ static
 ┃ ┃ ┗ myfrontend.js
 ┃ ┣ templates
 ┃ ┃ ┗ index.html
 ┃ ┣ tests
 ┃ ┃ ┣ __init__.py
 ┃ ┃ ┗ test_server.py
 ┃ ┣ __init__.py
 ┃ ┣ main.py
 ┃ ┗ utils.py
 ┣ Dockerfile
 ┗ requirements.txt
```

In `app/app/main.py` imports are:

```py
from app.utils import prepare_file

app = FastAPI()
```

and in `app/app/tests/test_server.py` imports are:

```py
from app.main import app
from app.utils import prepare_file
```

And the whole thing is run from a docker image built off [tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi](https://hub.docker.com/r/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi) by copying the files in and setting the workdir:

```
COPY ./app/app /app/app/
WORKDIR /app
```

This works with VSCode linting and testing, and with the QA toolchain:

```sh
pylint -E app/app # processes with no errors
pytest app/app/tests # correctly runs tests
docker build . -f app/Dockerfile -t myapp && docker container run myapp # app runs
```

**However**, PyCharm chokes on the imports:

```
Unresolved reference 'app'
Cannot find reference 'main' in 'imported module app'
Cannot find reference 'utils' in 'imported module app'
```

The PyCharm project has two submodules (the library with core "business logic" and the webapp that wraps it).

Pycharm can be made happy by changing `app/app/main.py` to:

```py
from ..app.utils import prepare_file
```

and `app/app/tests/test_server.py` to:

```py
from ...app.main import app
from ...app.utils import prepare_file
```

but this triggers pylint:

```sh
$ pylint -E app/app
************* Module app.main
app/app/main.py:18:0: E0402: Attempted relative import beyond top-level package (relative-beyond-top-level)
************* Module app.tests.test_server
app/app/tests/test_server.py:2:0: E0402: Attempted relative import beyond top-level package (relative-beyond-top-level)
app/app/tests/test_server.py:3:0: E0402: Attempted relative import beyond top-level package (relative-beyond-top-level)
```

I can think of two possible explanations:

1. PyCharm has a switch hidden somewhere that needs to be flipped to make it compatible. I tried marking `app/app` as "sources root" but it did not help.
2. The whole approach violates the correct structuring of a python web app and the whole thing should be restructured.

What do you think? Is this a PyCharm compatibility issue? Or a square peg round whole design problem?

Comment: Do you open with pycharm the topmost `app` folder among the two? For instance, if I open with VS code the second `app` or a further top folder, it hints me with an error too

Comment: Try setting first `app` as "sources root" in PyCharm

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Mark the `app` as "sources root" not `app/app`. Then pycharm sees what the other linters see.

Thanks @lsabi and @mx0 for the pointers.